# Thunderbird Email Client: Error 53000, "You can't get there from here"

Tags: firefox, email, browser, thunderbird, office365

I have been using Thunderbird to access Office365 emails for a while. Part way through today, I got the following error.

> [image]

I'm a bit surprised that Thunderbird doesn't use Firefox as its internal browser. I know they're somewhat separate these days, but still.

Anyone know how to fix this?

---

*Edit.* Some details requested below were only implicity given and some missing. So, I'm adding the missing ones and making explicit the implicit ones.

- It is indeed a work email address---the company is blocked out on the screenshot, but they ware the ones that provide the "management compliance policy". It does state that I need to change browser. I don't know what Thunderbird uses as its internal browser.
- What I did would be best summarised as "nothing". It was working at one point on Sunday. I turned my computer off, went out, turned it back on when I came back and was asked to sign in. Signing in, I got this message. This was on a *Sunday*, so I'd be a little surprised if anyone was changing settings at work then. They could be scheduled changes, of course.
- Using Windows 10, as per the image, with up-to-date Thunderbird, 102.7.2
- I've tried signing in multiple times as well as searching on the internet for solutions. Neither were successful. I also tried using my company's VPN, but that didn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a very hacky workaround.

- When the pop-up appears, asking to log in, I quickly copied the URL that appears in the top, before it redirected to a generic Microsoft one. It included some sort of token.
- I then went to this URL in a browser and logged in.
- After logging in, I got redirected to a 'local' link, which Firefox couldn't understand. This makes sense, as the link was instructed *Thunderbird* to do something. I just needed to enter this link into the Thunderbird pop-up.
- Doing this was not so easy, as the URL bar can't be typed in. However, I was able to click on various links and navigate to a webpage over which I had control. I put that link on that webpage, editing the webpage via my browser. I then clicked on this link and it worked.

This is one of the hackiest fixes I've come up with. I don't assume that it will work forever. So, if someone does have a real fix, please do let me know! Hopefully Thunderbird updates its internal browser soon...